# Unable to authenticate bluemix connection using eclipse paho c libraries

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am using the eclipse paho mqtt c library to connect to bluemix. Have done my part on the bluemix cloud and created an IoT device and registered the same, have generated API keys. But when i try to connect to the device using the below code, my code exits with an rc state of 5.
And i see log messages on the cloud saying "Closed connection, unable to authenticate".

I have tried a lot, but rc is always 5.

Appreciate your assistance.

I am using the below code, with my organization ID, device type, space ID and authentication token (on bluemix i have created a IoT device on watson).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include "MQTTClient.h"
#define CPU_TEMP "/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp"
using namespace std;

#define ADDRESS "tcp://<org_ID>.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:1883"
#define CLIENTID "d:<org_ID>:<Device_type>:<space_ID>"
#define AUTHMETHOD "use-token-auth"
#define AUTHTOKEN "<authentication_token>"
#define TOPIC "iot-2/evt/status/fmt/json"
#define QOS 1
#define TIMEOUT 10000L

float getCPUTemperature(){
    int CPUTemp;
    fstream fs;
    fs.open(CPU_TEMP, fstream::in);
    fs >> CPUTemp;
    fs.close();

    return (((float)CPUTemp)/1000);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MQTTClient client;
    MQTTClient_connectOptions opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
    MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
    MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
    MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID, MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);

    opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    opts.cleansession = 1;
    opts.username = AUTHMETHOD;
    opts.password = AUTHTOKEN;
    int rc;

    if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout<<"Failed to connect "<<rc<<endl;

        return -1;
    }

    stringstream message;

    message <<"{\"d\":{\"Temp\":"<<getCPUTemperature()<<"}}";
    pubmsg.payload = (char*) message.str().c_str();
    pubmsg.payloadlen = message.str().length();
    pubmsg.qos = QOS;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;

    MQTTClient_publishMessage(client, TOPIC, &pubmsg, &token);
    cout<< "Waiting for " << (int) (TIMEOUT/1000) << "seconds for pub of"<<message.str()<<"\non topic"<<TOPIC<<"for ClientID:"<<CLIENTID<<endl;
    rc = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client, token, TIMEOUT);
    cout<<"Message with token"<< (int)token<<"delivered"<<endl;
    MQTTClient_disconnect(client,10000);
    MQTTClient_destroy(&client);

    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Please provide you 6 character org ID so we can check the logs for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are 2 connection types on bluemix, TLS and non TLS.
So i was accessing TLS type using my code meant for non-TLS connections.
Hence the authent